# Length of a unicode string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode

In my Rails (2.3, Ruby 1.8.7) application, I need to truncate a string to a certain length. the string is unicode, and when running tests in console, such as `'א'.length`, I realized that a double length is returned. I would like an encoding-agnostic length, so that the same truncation would be done for a unicode string or a latin1 encoded string.

I've gone over most of the unicode material for Ruby, but am still a little in the dark. How should this problem be tackled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails has an `mb_chars` method which returns multibyte characters. Try `unicode_string.mb_chars.slice(0,50)`

Answer (score 3):

```
"ア".size # 3 in 1.8, 1 in 1.9
puts "ア".scan(/./mu).size # 1 in both 1.8 and 1.9
```

Answer (score 1):

`chars` and `mb_chars` don't give you text elements, which is what you seem to be looking for.

For text elements you'll want the [unicode gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/unicode).

mb_chars:

```
>> 'กุ'.mb_chars.size
=> 2

>> 'กุ'.mb_chars.first.to_s
=> "ก"
```

text_elements:

```
>> Unicode.text_elements('กุ').size
=> 1

>> Unicode.text_elements('กุ').first
=> "กุ"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `str.chars.slice(0, 50).join` to get the first 50 characters of a string, no matter how many bytes it uses per character.

Comment: In console, I get `undefined method `slice' for #<Enumerable::Enumerator:0xb67a0ed4>`